# I am facing problem for adding "implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1" in android studio(java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing problem for adding "implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1" in android studio(java).if I try to add this dependency then i face this problem,"error reading C:\Users\sourov ahmed.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex.rxjava3\rxjava\3.0.2\e652ec63717b1a92509abc8dc884fca0da3a974c\rxjava-3.0.2.jar; zip END header not found
"

My gradle code:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 32

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.andromart"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32`
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
implementation 'io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigat[enter image description here][1]ion:navigation-ui:2.5.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Comment: Try deleting the corrupted cache. Invalidation caches and restart.

Comment: @ItumelengTlali,Thanks for help.it worked. God bless you

Comment: You're welcome Sourov! Perhaps I can get some points for an approved answer haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the corrupted cache. Invalidation caches and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue but after importing below library it worked for me.

1. **Try to add below library:**

   ```
   implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.2")
   implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2")
   ```